# Getting latest entries from the revision table in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have a revision database table with multiple revisions for pages(pageId) under a website(webId).I want to write a query to get only the latest revisions of a website.For example the table below shows two files with id 1 and 2,now i want to get the revision number 101 and 104 as they are latest for their respective pages.I am using **mysql**

```
+----+---------+-------------+---------------------+-------+---------------------+
| id | userId  | webId       |revisionCont         | pageId| dateUpdated         |
+----+---------+-------------+---------------------+-------+---------------------+
| 100|       1 |           2 | some text           | 1     | 2014-01-07 08:00:00 |
| 101|       1 |           2 | some text           | 1     | 2014-01-07 08:01:00 |
| 103|       2 |           2 | some text           | 2     | 2014-01-07 08:15:32 |
| 104|       2 |           2 | some text           | 2     | 2014-01-07 09:10:32 |
+----+---------+-------------+---------------------+-------+---------------------+
```

I am not able to figure out how can I do it?Can someone guide me over it?

Comment: Did not think it was so simple!Thank you for the answers!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To obtain the complete row do:

```
SELECT * FROM revision WHERE Id IN (
  SELECT MAX(id) FROM revision GROUP BY pageId ORDER BY dateUpdated DESC
)
```

Comment: Accepting this as I needed the complete row.The previous answer was close but as @eKek0 pointed,I did not assume other things.I just checked the fiddle and assumed it worked.As per SO rules probably this has to be the best fit.Appologies for the mistake.

Answer (score 4):

try this

```
 SELECT max(id) id FROM revision 
 GROUP BY pageId
```

[**DEMO HERE**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/73aff/6)

output:

```
ID
104
101
```

EDIT: if you need to filrter or order the output then just add `ORDER BY dateUpdated DESC`

Comment: +1 . . . This answer is correct.  However, you don't need the `order by`.

Comment: @GordonLinoff yes thanks :) , i remove the order , and its up to him if he need it later

Comment: If you understand that the order of the revisions are due to the dateUpdated field, then you do need it to filter the last

Comment: @eKek0 . . . The OP does not state whether latest is based on `id` or `dateUpdated`.  It is reasonable to use an auto-incremented id for this purpose.  Given that the answer is accepted, this seems like a correct assumption.

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT MAX(id) id FROM revision GROUP BY pageId
```

Should do it.

Comment: See comment @Legionar's answer.

Answer (score 2):

Here is query example:

```
SELECT id FROM revision GROUP BY pageId ORDER BY dateUpdated DESC
```

It will get all records IDs (101 and 104), for each pageId, ordered by dateUpdated (descended)

Comment: nice one! for future visitros: add some query explanation what GROUP BY and ORDER BY does in that situation. :)=

Comment: This query is not guaranteed to work.  In fact, if it does, it is a coincidence.  The MySQL documentation *explicitly* warns against queries that select arbitrary columns in aggregation queries (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-extensions.html).  Plus the `order by` happens after the `group by` anyway.